# Model that belongs to one of two parents

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to decide on the best relationship structure for three models I have in a Rails app.

The models are candidate, an employer, and a video.

Sometimes a video will belong to an employer, other times a candidate. Because of this I am loathe to put foreign keys for both employer and candidate on a video, because it feels wrong that one will always be nil.

The problem with the code below is that the video will  *not* have many candidates, but I can't do a through relationship with belongs_to. What is a better way?

```
class Video < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :video_candidates
  has_many :candidates, :through => :video_candidates
end

class Candidate < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :video_candidates
  has_many :videos, :through => :video_candidates
end

class VideoCandidate < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :candidate
  belongs_to :vieo
end
```

Edit: Polymorphic association is the way to go. I'm going to put my solution below. Hope this helps someone.

```
class Video < ActiveRecord
    belongs_to :watchable, polymorphic: true
end

class Candidate < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :videos, as: :watchable
end

class Employer < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :videos, as: :watchable
end
```

And the migration

```
class CreateVideos < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :videos do |t|
      t.string :title
      t.belongs_to :watchable, polymorphic: true

      t.timestamps
    end
    add_index :videos, [:watchable_id, :watchable_type]
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an ideal case to go for [polymorphic association](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations)

Also refer [Railscast episode](http://railscasts.com/episodes/154-polymorphic-association)